# Review first post.

Tags: support, review

After posting a first post , how much time later a post is available for review.and For how longer it is available for one user.Because some times it shows one post for review but when I clicked it shows no item for review.

Comment: The reason might be that some else have already reviewed the post. (So it disappeared before the site with the list of posts to review was loaded.)

Comment: so review queue is shared among every one or it has some timestamp for every user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I watch every new post and its appearence time in review queue.Every first post that needs review,is queued arround 14-15 mintues later.